# Trying to pass new user information but TypeError occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What is the problem here?

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

and

> POST http://localhost:3001/signin 500 (Internal Server Error) xhr.js:220

> Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

/userRouter

```
const router = express.Router()
const User = require("../models/userModel")

router.route("/signin").post((req, res, next) =>{
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const newUser = new User({
        email,
        password
    });

    newUser.save()
})

module.exports = router;
```

/userModel

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: '',
    password: ''
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

module.exports = User;
```

/server

```
const app = express()
const cors =  require("cors")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express())

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://daw_dzieniszewski:******@cluster0.mn9uw.mongodb.net/firma_edukacyjna")

//require route
app.use("/", require("./backend/routes/userRoute"))

app.listen(3001, function (){
    console.log("express  server  is running on port 3001")
})
```

/SigninC

```
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap"
import axios from "axios";

function SignInC() {


    const [input, setInput] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    })

    function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target;

        setInput(prevInput => {
            return {
                ...prevInput,
                [name]: value
            }
        })
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(input);
        const newUser = {
            email: input.email,
            password:input.password
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/signin', newUser)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className="p-5 m-3 d-sm-flex">
            <Container className="container-sm w-auto p-5 border rounded-4 bg-light">
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label htmlFor="InputEmail" 
                                   className="form-label fs-4">Email address</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange} 
                                   name="email" value={input.email} 
                                   type="email"
                                   className="form-control form-control-sm"
                                   id="exampleInputEmail1"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label htmlFor="InputPassword1" 
                                   className="form-label fs-4">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" 
                                   className="form-control" 
                                   id="exampleInputPassword1"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label htmlFor="InputPassword2" 
                                   className="form-label fs-4">Repeat password</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange} 
                                   value={input.password} 
                                   name="password" 
                                   type="password"
                                   className="form-control" 
                                   id="exampleInputPassword2"></input>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={handleClick} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}


export default SignInC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `await newUser.save()` instead of `newUser.save()` in your userRouter.js and make the function async
`async (req,res,next)`

Comment: Still the same errors